# Search and replace programme with c doesn't work fine?

Tags: c, argv, argc

hey everyone i have a problem to solve with c but the programme doesnt work fine
this is the subject :

> Write a program called search_and_replace that takes 3 arguments, the
> first arguments is a string in which to replace a letter (2nd
> argument) by another one (3rd argument). If the number of arguments is
> not 3, just display a newline. If the second argument is not contained
> in the first one (the string) then the program simply rewrites the
> string followed by a newline.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> $>./search_and_replace "Papache est un sabre" "a" "o"
> Popoche est un sobre
> ```

and this the full code ;

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;   
    int replace;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    if (argc == 4)
    {
        while(argv[1][i])
        {
            while(argv[2][j] != '\0' && argv[1][i] == argv[2][j])
            {
                while(argv[3][k])
                {
                    k = 0;
                    replace = argv[2][j];
                    argv[2][j] = argv[3][k];
                    argv[3][k] = replace;
                    k++;
                }
                argv[1][i] = argv[2][j];
                j++;
            }
            write(1, &argv[1][i], 1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

i'm trying to change variables declaration inside the loops and also make all condition in juste 2 while

Comment: "*warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'k' used*". Please do take notice of compiler warnings.

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: In the first iteration of `while(argv[3][k])` the variable `k` has an indeterminate value. You must explicitly initialise local (automatic) variables, as you did with `i = 0; j = 0;`. Your `k = 0;` is in the wrong place inside that loop, which does `k++;` but then resets it next time.

Comment: can you write the correct logic for me , i dont get the error

Comment: You only need to iterate through the string once to check for occurrences of the character to replace. The variable k is used in the innermost loop, but it's initialized within that same loop. This would reset k to 0 in every iteration, leading to an infinite loop if the characters match.
Consider a single loop that goes through the string in argv[1]. For each character, if it matches argv[2][0], you print the character from argv[3][0]. Otherwise, you print the original character.

Comment: Move `j = 0;` and `k = 0;` to *just before* the nested loops that use them. Both are in the wrong place.

Comment: It would be easier if you used `for` loops instead of `while` loops. Then it's almost automatic to initialize the variable at the appropriate time.

Comment: First step of debugging is finding a way to describe the symptoms pf "the programme doesnt work fine". So please give details of how it fails. I can tell that you do not match the requirement to output a newline if the nuber of paramters is incorrect, but you are probably focusing on other things.

Comment: The second parameter is a single letter, so is the third. So what are you trying to access with `argv[2][j]` for j!=0?

Comment: Frankly I get the impression that you are quoting an assignment and then ask to "fix" random code in order to camouflage that you really only want people here to write the program for you. In order to change that impression please comment your code generously and rename your single-letter identifiers, so that your thinking for each of your code lines becomes clear. Alternatively at least explain what each of your three loops is for.

Comment: the expected output is to change every a in the first argument to b with this commande  : ./a.out "abcabc abcabc" "a" "b" but the output has change only the first a in the argument : bbcabc abcabc%

Comment: Interesting, though that was already clear from the assignment, please [edit] to provide that kind of information in the question. Go on trying for [ask], which you seem to have just found and start to apply. Good work - more of that please. You might also like the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You have several unnecessary loops. The 2nd and 3rd arguments are just single characters, not strings that you need to loop over. You just replace any occurrences of `argc[2][0]` with `argc[3][0]`.

You also don't need to swap characters between `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` when you find a match.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 4 && strlen(argc[2]) > 0 && strlen(argc[3]) > 0)
    {
        char *string = argc[1];
        char old = argc[2][0];
        char new = argc[3][0];

        for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++) {
            if (string[i] == old) {
                string[i] = new;
            }
        }
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, string, strlen(string));
    }
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1); // write a newline after the replacement
}
```